# Importing Contacts error "Name"

Tags: import

I am trying to import contacts and keep getting a name error. I have checked my data and it is accurate. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Are you mapping a field from your data to the Name Field on the contact object?

Comment: Yes, I am mapping Contact Name in Salesforce to the Contact Name Column in my CSV.

Comment: I tried to split the name between first and last and are still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is a read-only field on the Contact object.  You need to split the name in your import file and map to the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields instead.  See the [Contact object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) reference page.